# Visual Studio Debugging/Building

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, compiler-construction, build

I have a solution that has a plain old asp.net website and a winforms app.

I have the winforms app set as my startup application.

When I press (CTRL+)F5, it just runs the app without building. So, my changes aren't built into the program.

What should I do to fix this?

### EDIT

I don't want to have to go to the build menu and then debug. I want a single step.

### EDIT 2

This is VS 2008 SP1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to go into the properties for my solution and select the projects that I want to include during builds.

Answer (score 0):

Build->Build Solution (press F6)

For direct debugging (press F5)

Comment: That doesn't start the program. It just builds the source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTRL+SHIFT+B for building before hitting F5. Thats not a single step, but it's not using the mouse.

But it sure seems strange that it does not compile first if there are changes. It use to do that here at my computer.

Answer (score 0):

in visual studio,go to tools,import and export settings,reset.
hope this might help